# Arduino Timer count resets at 65 but it should reset at 70

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to display a timer which counts up to 70 seconds however once it reaches 65, it restarts (loop). This happened after I added `basetime=millis();` and `currtime = millis()-basetime;`. (It works when I remove those two but I added because I want the `millis()` to be reset to zero once it hits 70 seconds). 
Anybody able to help me on this?
Let me know if my full code is needed. Thanks!

```cpp
void loop() {
    basetime = millis();
    seconds = 0;
    seconds2 = 0;
    minutes = 0;


    for (seconds == 0; seconds <= 70; seconds++) {
        time();
    }
}

void time() {
    currtime = millis() - basetime;
    tft.textSetCursor(100, 100);
    tft.textColor(RA8875_WHITE, RA8875_RED);
    sprintf(timeline, "%02d hours %02d mins %02d secs", hours, minutes, seconds2);
    tft.print(timeline);
    delay(1000);

    tft.textSetCursor(200, 300);
    tft.textColor(RA8875_WHITE, RA8875_RED);
    tft.print("Deg C = ");
    tft.print(ktc.readCelsius());
    delay(1000);

    seconds = currtime / 1000;
    minutes = (currtime / 1000) / 60;
    seconds2 = seconds - (minutes * 60);
    minutes = minutes - (hours * 60);
    hours = ((millis() / 1000) / 60) / 60;
}
```

Comment: Normally we don't reset arduino millis() but handle roll over.

Comment: for (seconds == 0; ...) should be for (seconds = 0; ....)

Comment: Can't see all the code.  What variable types are you using for those variables.  That's going to matter in some of the math steps.  The 65 number for seconds makes me think you are probably overflowing an int somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check rhe following:

basetime and currtime should be defined long - before the setup routine 
Arduino style

```
unsigned long currtime, basetime;
```

or initialized c style

```
uint32_t currtime = 0;
uint32_t basetime = 0;
```

and get rid of the delay(s) in your code -this stops processing at that point.
More info in blink without delay (built in example Arduino IDE -> File -> Examples -> 02,Digital -> BlinkWithoutDelay)

The 65 sec problem is the roll over of an int (probably set to uint16_t by the compiler -> max value it can hold 2^16-1  (**65**.535) then rollover (bethoven)